# Auto adding map elements using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am very new with Python scripting in ArcGIS Desktop.

Just wondering if there is a way to auto add in map elements?

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question  to provide more details about the type of map element you want to add and what you mean by "auto adding", please?

Answer (score 1):

arcpy.mapping (LegendElement) should do the trick.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000041000000

Allows you to access properties of elements and reposition, etc.